# How should I refer to this random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $(\Gamma,\mathscr{G})$ be a measurable space. Then a random probability measure on $(\Gamma,\mathscr{G})$ can be defined as a function $M\colon \Omega \times \mathscr{G} \to [0,1]$ such that

1. For all $\omega \in \Omega$, the function $M_\omega\colon A \mapsto M(\omega,A)$ is a probability measure on $(\Gamma,\mathscr{G})$,
2. For all $A \in \mathscr{G}$, the function $M_A\colon \omega \mapsto M(\omega,A)$ is a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$.

This definition is based on chapter VI of Çınlar's *Probability and Stochastics*.

Let $X$ be a measurable function on $(\Gamma,\mathscr{G})$. Then $X$ is a random variable on each probability space $(\Gamma,\mathscr{G},M_\omega)$, and Fubini's theorem implies that the function
$$
\omega \mapsto \int_\Gamma  X \,\mathrm{d}M_\omega
$$
is a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$. Is there any particular name for such a random variable? From what I understand here, I would be tempted to call this random variable the "random expectation" of $X$ with respect to the random probability measure $M$. However, I've never seen the phrase "random expectation" anywhere, so I'm not sure if it is indeed a correct interpretation, or if another name is usually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation is to realize everything on the same space (the sensible thing to do in probability: enrich your measured space as needed):

$$\begin{align}
Y & = \Omega \times \Gamma, \\
\mathcal{Y} & = \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}, \\
\mu (B \times A) & = \int_B M_\omega (A) \ d\mathbb{P} (\omega).
\end{align}$$

Then $(Y, \mathcal{Y}, \mu)$ is a probabilized space. We can define $X = X(\gamma)$ on $Y$, but depending only on the second coordinate. Then

$$\int_\Gamma X(\gamma) \ d M_\omega (\gamma) = \mathbb{E} (X|\omega),$$

so you are looking at the conditional expectation of $X$ knowing $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks! I did not see it this way, but indeed it also makes sense to combine the spaces.